# Firebase storage security rules with specific path exceptions?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to use storage rules to limit read an write to my whole paths with an exception, I mean:

- Write and read can be done in any path only with authentication.
- The only path that can be written by public but readable by auth user is "/appUsers"

I've tried with no success:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /appUsers {
        allow write;
        allow read : if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read,write : if request.auth != null;
    } 
  }
}
```

With that code, Im only allowed to read and/or write with authentication.

How can I achieve this particular security rule?

Comment: How are you testing this? The rules Playground or a production application? What you're asking works for me in the console Rules Playground

Comment: @ScottCrossen OMG you are right, I've tested on firebase simulator and seems to work pretty fine. Im writing from a React Native application. Even if I set allPaths to public write, the app is not able to write its upload

Comment: That seems to me to indicate that rules isn't the issue then. I'm not sure how to help. It's odd that you're able to write but just with authentication. You might be using the wrong SDK (GCS vs Firebase vs Firebase Admin).